# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 - don't navigate 'back' to a Dialog page

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

Prior to JQM 1.4, I created dialogues using `data-role="dialog"` and those pages were not added to the back stack, so navigating off one and then pressing back would bring you to the page before the dialog.

Now with 1.4.5, dialogues are defined as `data-role="page"` with `data-dialog="true"`. Using this method, the dialog is added to the back stack, so if I navigate off the dialog and then tap back I am returned to the dialog.  This is not the behavior I want.  Is there a way, when the dialog opens, to tell JQM NOT to add it to the back stack?

Comment: I've updated my code, it had a problem in navigating back to dialog from true page.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, *dialog* widget is deprecated and will be removed in 1.5. It is now converted into a page - as you've mentioned - with `data-dialog="true"`.

When you navigate to a *dialog*, jQM updates framework's navigation history as well as browser's navigation history. Even if you navigate to a *dialog* programmatically with `changeHash` disabled, when you hit back button, you will redirected to second previous history record.

A work around is to listen to `pagecontainerbeforechange` and alter `toPage` to navigate to the page where the *dialog* was called.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if (typeof data.toPage == "string" && data.options.direction == "back") {
        var active = $.mobile.navigate.history.activeIndex;
        for (var i = active; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!$($.mobile.navigate.history.stack[i].hash).hasClass("ui-dialog") && !$($.mobile.navigate.history.stack[i].hash).hasClass("ui-page-active")) {
                data.toPage = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[i].url;
                data.options.transition = "flip";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When you want to alter `toPage`, it should be a `string` and not an `object`. The event fires twice on each navigation, it returns `string` first and then an `object`.

When it returns a `string`, check navigation direction `options.direction`. If the direction is `back`, loop through `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack` in reversed order. The previous record should not be a dialog `ui-dialog` nor the active page `ui-page-active`. If both conditions return true, alter `toPage`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hwm3fvsj/)**

Comment: This messes up my page .. this runs every time I select an item in a drop down, so the javascript that the changed event should be running does not run.

Comment: @Christine the code above needs to be amended to fit your requirements, it is not out-of-the-box magical solution.

Comment: We decided to go in a different way and remove all of the dialogs and convert them to other controls.  It's very frustrating that JQM removed this control without providing a comparable alternative.  I'm replacing some with popups, but not if they have drop downs on them, and I'm auditioning other solutions.  The pagecontainerbeforechange event just caused too many other issues to be a viable solution as it isn't just triggered on a page change.