# jQuery Mobile: page popups interfering with each other

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've got two narrowed down html files, i1.html and i2.html -- they are nearly identical, should be easily runnable.

i1.html (page1) has a popup1 page that allows the user to stay on page1 or go to i2.html (page2).

i2.html (page2) has a popup2 page that is supposed to allow the user to stay on page2 or go to i1.html (page1).

The problem I'm having in both Chrome and Firefox is the page1 popup works to get the user over to i2.html (page2).  But once on i2.html, it won't navigate to page1.  The popup won't respond.  If I do a shift refresh, it will, but one can notice the popup page is messed up (two many buttons appear, looks like from i1.html.)

A related question I have is, how does one debug a button not doing anything. Thanks.

i1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>i1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
       <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Page 1</h1>
       </div>
       <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <p><a href="#popup1" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Navigate via popup dialog</a></p>
       </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
           <h1>page bottom</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Start #popup page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="popup1">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Dialog</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h2>Popup</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p><a href="#page1" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back to page one</a></p>
            <p><a href="i2.html" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Go to Page2</a></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Pop up Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page popup -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And i2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>i2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
       <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Page 2</h1>
       </div>
       <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <p><a href="#popup2" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Navigate via popup dialog</a></p>
       </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
           <h1>page bottom</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Start #popup page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="popup2">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Dialog</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h2>Popup2</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back to page 2</p>
            <p><a href="i1.html" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Go to Page 1</a></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Pop up Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page popup -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in regards to (A related question I have is, how does one debug a button not doing anything) -- open chromes browser console -- if there is an error then the console will show it -- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: Console doesn't show anything

Comment: try a popup rather than a dialog -- see here how to properly set one up http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/ --

Comment: anyway check here -- dialogs are a no no as of 1.4..4 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367056/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-dont-navigate-back-to-a-dialog-page

Comment: exactly, I tried the dialog and it didn't work (same problem) and I abandoned it per deprecation.

Comment: Using a page should work, right?

Comment: well i assume if dialog was removed in 1.5 that also means (data-rel="dialog") does nothing. check the JQM website to clarify

Comment: Note:  dialog is not removed yet, that's in 1.5, and the current version is 1.45.  Back to the main issue, did you test the code and get the same results?

Comment: ok ill  test the code and let you know -- give me a few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i did a Test

Whats happening is that JQM loads in pages via ajax. When you navigate to page 2 this

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h2>Popup2</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p><a href="#page2" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back to page 2</p>
            <p><a href="i1.html" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Go to Page 1</a></p>
        </div>
```

gets stripped off as i suspect you have `<div role="main" class="ui-content">` on the other page hence the button is not working because their is no DOM code to run.

[image]

Turning off ajax navigation off fixes the issue `data-ajax="false"`

```
   <p><a href="i1.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Go to Page 1</a></p>

   <p><a href="i2.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Go to Page2</a></p>
```

More info here

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

works ok now

Comment: Thanks.  How did you debug that if I may ask.   Also, doesn't ajax go to a server (by definition).  Which server?  I'm reading the doc you mentioned but I don't get how they are referring to ajax because there is no server??

Comment: Well its been a good year or so since i did any projects using JQM and to be honest i stayed away from dialogs because their a pane in arse :)) so i used popups. How i debuged it and saw what the problem is, was when i when i navigated to page 2 i inspected in chrome the button (hover on the button, right click, inspect) and saw that part of page 2 code wasnt loaded in so then i realized the AJAX thing from memory when i read the docs years ago

Comment: Would you please help me understand what AJAX means in this context (it's obviously not server communication, right?)

Comment: AJAX is built in to  Jquery, you can use it to load html pages, or make requests to a server etc -- more info here -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Oh, I must be sleepy, I got it -- it gets an html page from the server.  Thanks.  I thought I avoided the deprecated dialog (where they indicated) but obviously did not using the page example they give.  I'm going to switch to popups now;  is there a reason popups can't hold a lot of content, like some other input questions and answers that I check in the client?  I'm trying to avoid having any server software for this site (just use html pages).  Every server seems so complex to me, for example just running grails last time getting the jetty server to work right to run grails was hard for me.

Comment: @Ray -- well as i remember i had full page popup's with various elements, buttons, search boxes, pictures etc. You can modify the css of the popup -- try a one page template, and have all your pages in there, unless you really want separate htm pages

Comment: Cool, thanks much.  May I please ask, since we're down in a note here, what you feel is the simplest web server and software/language to run (on basic hosting plans like godaddy -- it's linux but it's a shared server).   Is any of it relatively easy?

Comment: @Ray -- depends, i host my own servers at home and pass the wan IP over to my domain name with go daddy. Maybe its the country i live in but my WAN IP has been the same on my router for years now, so no probs there. Larger countries like the UK may renew the address every so often and that may be a problem cause you need to change that in Go daddy. If you have a business and a router, it would be more economic if you host a linux web server there or virtualise one on a pc using Virtualbox. But as long as the ISP doesnt change he WAN ip whenever they feel like, you be in the clear

Comment: @Ray - and yes, its easy. with Ubuntu linux server or desktop you can be Up and running in 5 minutes  -- (sudo tasksel install  lamp-server) will install, Apachec webserver, mysql, and php all in one go -- there is some learning curver but trust me its easy after checking a few tutorials on how to

Comment: Thanks I have AMP on my machine, to use Mysql and have Apache.  So you recommend using php as the language?  Is there an alternative to PHP that can run in the same Apache server (without an app server added in), that you can recommend?  I never learned PHP, I have a Java background, but Java before all the heavy web "crap", so much complexity I find (at least for me).  Like versions of libraries not working right, hours and hours spent investigating mis-matches, etc.  Has PHP evolved into a pretty "decent" programming language (I know it's one of the first web-languages, that and cgi scripts)

Comment: @Ray -- well here is the thing -- for the web, Apache, PHP, and mysql would be pretty much all you will need. PHP is very very powerfull. Saying that with linux you could also install any other Language on the planet, eg python, perl, java  etc and use them too.  Apache, PHP, and mysql are there bundled together because they work together Fast when it comes to the web. If you know java you will see similarities in PHP, its not that hard to learn. The documentation is great

Comment: Ok, thanks Tasos.  I think I've avoided PHP over the years because it seems like an outdated language compared to all the others, but perhaps not?  is there a PHP framework you recommend, or do you do PHP from "scratch"?

Comment: @Ray -- can be that outdated when its the No 6 most used language on the globe. and 3 of the top spots are taken up by C versions -- http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html -- were did you hear it was outdated?

Comment: Good point.  I thought so perhaps because it was the first web language other than cgi-scripting (I believe, may be wrong).  Thanks for showing me that.  Do you use Laravel or another framework when coding doing PHP?  http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-framework-2015-sitepoint-survey-results/

Comment: @Ray -- ha ha and Logo is No 34 -- i used that language back in 80's -- it was developed by the Apollo Space program to land a man on the moon. Still hanging in there

Comment: @Ray -- No i never used those frameworks, but they are popular.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!   Have a great night Bro.

Comment: @Ray -- you too -- when you get a chance, vote for my Answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, don't know why I forgot.  Thanks again.